# Create a unique id from x and y integers and back

Tags: java, math, numbers, identity

I'm working on a program, where the developer decides to create unique ids from `x` and `y` values. The id is calculated this way:

```
id = toInteger(toString(x) + toString(x+y) + toString(y));
```

Any idea how I could get the `x` and `y` values out of such ids?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean? It is being argued that you want to extract the _x_ and _y_ values from the ID instead of creating and ID based on the concatenation you showed in your question. I provided an answer based on my interpretation, but I my interpretation of what you need could be wrong.

Comment: You cannot. If for example the ID is 13130, it could stem from x = 1 and y = 30 or from x = 13 and y = 0. BTW you cannot always produce an ID that way. The formula overflows for relatively small numbers (x = 500, y = 501) and it doesn’t work if y is negative.

Comment: If you can assume x and y are > 0, a brute force approach is manageable. ID is at most 10 digits long, and the length of x + y is either the longest of x and y or 1 more than that. So simply try all possible combinations of lengths. There can be at most 5 such combinations, I think, at least not much more.

Comment: May I ask if this is homework or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Random` class to generate a random number inside a given range. This example prompts the user to enter the lower and upper limits for the randomly generated numbers. Then, use your snippet to generate the ID. I used `Long` to hold the value in case your upper limit is large.

```
public class RandomInRange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the lower limit value: " );
        int lowerLimit = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the upper limit value: " );
        int upperLimit = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(lowerLimit, upperLimit + 1);
        int y = random.nextInt(lowerLimit, upperLimit + 1);
        Long id = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(x) + String.valueOf(x+y) + String.valueOf(y));

        System.out.println("x = " + x + "; y = " + y);
        System.out.println("ID: " + id);
    }
}
```

The output of one of my runs:

```
Enter the lower limit value: 43
Enter the upper limit value: 87
x = 43; y = 85
ID: 4312885
```

As you can see, the ID is 43 - 128 - 85. 128 is 85 + 43. The "43" was equal to the lower limit by coincidence.

Another sample run:

```
Enter the lower limit value: 43
Enter the upper limit value: 87
x = 53; y = 66
ID: 5311966
```

Since the upper bound of the randomizing function is exclusive, I added 1 to the number entered by the user to make the upper limit value inclusive.

Comment: I don't see  how this answers the question.  The OP wants to compute the inverse of the function to find the `x` and `y` values that resulted in the Id.  So given some value `5311966`, the OP expects you to return `53` and `66`.  And I suspect there could be more than one pair of values for a single id.

Answer (score 0):

The number of digits in x is between 1 and `(number of digits of id) - 2`. The number of digits in y is between 1 and `(number of digits in id) - (number of digits in x) - 1`. The number of digits in x+y is the rest.

This method returns the x and y pairs in a 2-element array of integers. and returns null if not found.

```
static int[] originalXandY(int id) {
    String idStr = Integer.toString(id);
    int idLen = idStr.length();
    for (int xLen = id < 0 ? 2 : 1; xLen <= idLen - 2; ++xLen) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(idStr.substring(0, xLen));
        for (int yLen = 1; yLen <= idLen - xLen - 1; ++yLen) {
            int y = Integer.parseInt(idStr.substring(idLen - yLen));
            if (x + y == Integer.parseInt(idStr.substring(xLen, idLen - yLen)))
                return new int[] {x, y};
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalXandY(121)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalXandY(124634)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalXandY(1346345)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalXandY(123412439)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalXandY(123456)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalXandY(22220)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originalXandY(-112)));
```

output:

```
[1, 1]
[12, 34]
[1, 345]
[1234, 9]
null
[2, 20]
[-1, 2]
```

**Caution:**
If id is `22220` there are two solutions
`x = 22, y = 0` and `x = 2, y = 20`. Note that this method returns only one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that should return all possible values of `x` and `y` which meet the criteria.

- I created lambdas for the generation and reversal processes.
- The generation lambda returns a string to avoid possible overflow when converting to an int.
- I use a `Set<XY>` of records to house the results in case there is more than one solution.  A class could also serve this purpose.
- This does not support negative values of `x` or `y`.

This uses two nested loops.  The first loop iterates forward on the ID while the nested loop iterates backwards on the starting at the end. If the id generated from those two values equals the source ID the values are stored in a record and added to a set.  When complete, the set is returned.

```
record XY(int x, int y) {}

BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String> getId = (a, b) -> Integer.toString(a)
        + Integer.toString(a + b) + b;

Function<String, Set<XY>> reverse = (id) -> {
     Set<XY> results = new HashSet<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < id.length(); i++) {
         long first = Long.parseLong(id.substring(0, i + 1));
         for (int k = id.length() - 1; k > i; k--) {
             long last = Long.parseLong(id.substring(k));
             if (getId.apply((int) first, (int) last).equals(id)) {
                 results.add(new XY((int) first, (int) last));
             }
         }
     }
     return results;
 };


Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = r.nextInt(100);
    int y = r.nextInt(200);
    String id = getId.apply(x,y);
    System.out.printf("%3d  %3d -> %10s :  %s\n", x,y, id, 
       reverse.apply(id));
}
```

prints something like

```
 83   50 ->    8313350 :  [XY[x=83, y=50]]
 70   34 ->    7010434 :  [XY[x=70, y=34]]
 63  175 ->   63238175 :  [XY[x=63, y=175]]
 60    2 ->      60622 :  [XY[x=60, y=2]]
 56   29 ->     568529 :  [XY[x=56, y=29]]
 10   23 ->     103323 :  [XY[x=10, y=23]]
 94  104 ->   94198104 :  [XY[x=94, y=104]]
 89   51 ->    8914051 :  [XY[x=89, y=51]]
 78  150 ->   78228150 :  [XY[x=78, y=150]]
 40    5 ->      40455 :  [XY[x=40, y=5]]
```

And to further illustrate [Ole V.V's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) observation in the comments.

```
String id = getId.apply(1, 30);
Set<XY> res = reverse.apply(id);
System.out.printf("%3d  %3d -> %10s :  %s\n", 1, 30, id, res);
```

prints

```
1   30 ->      13130 :  [XY[x=13, y=0], XY[x=1, y=30]]
```